# Check if youtube video player is playing (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

```js
    YouTubePlayerView youtubeplayerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        youtubeplayerview.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo("videoId", 0);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

How to check if youtube video player is playing in android studio? and How do I get to the virtual pause button on a youtube video.

I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: Do you want to check whether a YouTube video is played (by embedding) it in your application or do you want to check whether there is a video playing from the normal YouTube application? And what exactly do you mean with virtual pause button?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#isPlaying()

Comment: Thank you but I have no idea how to use it.